# group by issue in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like:

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total, remaining
FROM cold_clients, (
   SELECT count( * ) AS remaining
   FROM cold_clients
   WHERE sic_code = '754901'
   AND STATUS = 'COLD'
) AS r
WHERE sic_code = '754901';
```

I am getting correct result for total sic codes and remaining sic codes.
But, it's specific for particular value of sic code.
I want to get all the sic codes with it's total and remaining values.

I have tried with group by, but, it's giving me wrong values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT count( * ) AS total,
       sum(STATUS = 'COLD') as remaining
FROM cold_clients
WHERE sic_code = '754901';
```

For all the `sic_code`s, use aggregation:

```
SELECT sic_code, count(*) AS total,
       sum(STATUS = 'COLD') as remaining
FROM cold_clients
GROUP BY sic_code;
```

Comment: I don't want it for specific sic code that is: 754901. I want this information for all the sic codes which are in database.